# Cocoa Touch: Trouble populating 2D array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I am writing an app that uses SQLITE3.  I am populating array with a value located in a double-dimensioned array (matrix).  When I do this, I am getting an ASSERTION error and I cannot figure out why:

ViewController.h

```
    matrix1 [25][1000];
    array1 [2000];
```

ViewController.m

Populating array1 at index matrix[i][j], with the value in matrix1[i][j]

```
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++){
for(int j = 0;j<25; j++)
 {
   array1[matrix1[matrix1[i][j]];
 }
}

  ...


if(sqlite3_exec(pb_database,[pb_update_string UTF8String]
              ,NULL,NULL,&errormsg)!= SQLITE_OK) {
   NSAssert1(0, @"Error updating tables: ==> %s <==", errormsg);
   sqlite3_free(errormsg);
   NSLog(@"line not update");
}
```

The error is always on the INSERT/REPLACE statement.

Comment: Please edit your question to add some more information. Include your INSERT/REPLACE statement code, add the actual error you're getting, etc.

Comment: dude you need to reverse the i and j in the for loop. It will give you EXC_BAD_ACCESS otherwise.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with this statement any way array1[matrix1[matrix1[i][j]];

Comment: I will add the error that I am getting.  I am loading the array with values that I receive from a URL.  I load the values into a 2D array. I am taking the values from the 2D array at position X,Y and for each occurerence of value Z, ai am populating array1 at index Z with that value.

I figured the indexes in my example might be backwards, just typing ahead of myself.

The error is:

2011-01-24 23:18:01.904 BallPower[23068:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error updating tables: ==> (null) <=='
*** Call stack at first throw:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You're using the SQLite C API directly.  Don't do this unless you have a very good reason.   [Use FMDB instead](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).  It will make your life *much* easier.
2. Your arrays are not the same size.  One contains 25,000 elements (25*1000), and the other contains 2,000 elements.
3. Your `for` loop does nothing.  `array1[matrix1[matrix1[i][j]];` is not only syntactically incorrect (you're missing a closing square bracket), but it doesn't *do* anything.
4. Your SQLite code has absolutely nothing to do with your `for` loop.